# Compiled binary path based on compiler options

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies

I have a large program and library written in C++ and built with make. About a dozen options that are set in the makefile turn into preprocessor directives that change the implementation (with `ifdef`s, etc.). Right now I'm brute-forcing my build process by `make clean`ing when I change these compiler options before I run the code. I'd like to set up the system so that the binary's name changes based on the options. But, I'm worried that I'm going to miss one or add one in the future and forget to change the name, etc. Is there a clean way to handle this problem?

Some options I've considered:

1. manually create a binary name, such as APP.#{OPT_1}.#{OPT_2}.#{OPT_3}.#{OPT_4} when I build, and then run that one
2. create a hash (e.g., SHA1) from all of the compiler flags (CXXFLAGS) and put that hash into the name of my binary, such as APP.#{SHA1(CXXFLAGS)}. This has the value of extensibility in the future.

Any better approaches / recommendations?

Comment: Just as a side question, how does your testing adapt to the changed name?

Comment: The test uses preprocessor variables with `ifdef`s to change the source code pre-compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any better approaches / recommendations?

If I understand correctly, your GNU Make build system can build several variants of
your executable, differentiated by preprocessor macros that are defined (or not)
in the compilation commands depending on conditions that are tested in your Makefile
and/or on the arguments that you pass to `make`. And you want to be able to build
any of these variants independently, without needing a `make clean` to remove the
artifacts of the previous build, which might well have been a build of a different
variant.

This is one of the basic needs of build systems. The conventional solution is not the
one you're thinking about - to somehow encode differentiations into the name of
the executable. That won't work anyway, unless you do the same thing with the names of
the *object* files that are linked into the executable. If you don't, then when
you switch from variant *X* to variant *Y*, a variant-*X* object file `foo.o`
that is not older than `foo.cpp`, will not need to be recompiled,
even if *should* be for variant-*Y*, and that variant-*X* `foo.o` will be linked into the
variant *Y* executable, no matter what it is called.

The conventional solution is to differentiate, per variant, the *place* where the compiler
will output the object files and correspondingly the *place* where the linker
outputs the executable. No doubt all of the C/C++ IDEs you have ever used allow you
to build either a *debug* variant or a *release* variant of your project, and
they differentiate the *debug* object files and executable from the *release* object
files and executables by generating them in different *subdirectories* of the
project directory, e.g.

```
<projdir>/Debug/{obj|bin}
<projdir>/Release/{obj|bin}
```

or maybe:

```
<projdir>/obj/{debug|release}
<projdir>/bin/{debug|release}
```

This approach automatically encodes the variant of an object file or executable
into its *absolute pathname*,e.g.

```
<projdir>/Debug/obj/foo.o
<projdir>/bin/release/prog
```

without any further ado, and the variants can be built independently.

It's straightforward to implement this scheme in a makefile. Most of the IDEs
that use it *do* implement it in the makefiles that they generate behind the scenes.
And it's also straightforward to extend the scheme to more variants than just *debug*
and *release* (although whatever variants you want, you'll certainly want *debug*
and *release* variants of those variants).

Here's an illustration for a toy program that we want to build in any of the
variants that we get for combinations of two build-properties that we'll call
`TRAIT_A` and `TRAIT_B`:

```
 | TRAIT_A | TRAIT_B |
 |---------|---------|
 |    Y    |    Y    |
 |---------|---------|
 |    Y    |    N    |
 |---------|---------|
 |    N    |    Y    |
 |---------|---------|
 |    N    |    N    |
```

*And* we want to be able to build any of those variants in debug mode or release
mode. `TRAIT_{A|B}` might map directly to a preprocessor macro, or to an
arbitrary combination of preprocessor flags, compiler options and/or linkage options.

Our program, `prog`, is built from just one source file:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int atgc, char * argv[])
{
    std::string cmd{"readelf -p .GCC.command.line "};
    cmd += argv[0];
    return system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

And all it does is invoke `readelf` to dump the linkage section `.GCC.command.line`
within its own executable. That linkage section only exists when we compile or
link with the GCC option [`-frecord-gcc-switches`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options).
So purely for the purpose of the demo we'll always compile and link with that option.
Here's a makefile that adopts one way of differentiating all the variants:
object files are compiled in `./obj[/trait...]`; executables are linked in
`./bin[/trait...]`:

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS := -frecord-gcc-switches
BINDIR := ./bin
OBJDIR := ./obj

ifdef RELEASE
ifdef DEBUG
$(error RELEASE and DEBUG are mutually exclusive)
endif
CPPFLAGS := -DNDEBUG
CXXFLAGS += -O3
BINDIR := $(BINDIR)/release
OBJDIR := $(OBJDIR)/release
endif

ifdef DEBUG
ifdef RELEASE
$(error RELEASE and DEBUG are mutually exclusive)
endif
CXXFLAGS += -O0 -g
BINDIR := $(BINDIR)/debug
OBJDIR := $(OBJDIR)/debug
endif

ifdef TRAIT_A
CPPFLAGS += -DTRAIT_A   # or whatever
BINDIR := $(BINDIR)/TRAIT_A
OBJDIR := $(OBJDIR)/TRAIT_A
endif

ifdef TRAIT_B
CPPFLAGS += -DTRAIT_B   # or whatever
BINDIR := $(BINDIR)/TRAIT_B
OBJDIR := $(OBJDIR)/TRAIT_B
endif

SRCS :=  main.cpp
OBJS := $(OBJDIR)/$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
EXE := $(BINDIR)/prog

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS) | $(BINDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $<

$(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(EXE) $(OBJS)
```

Now let's build, say, two variants in debug mode and two other variants in
release mode, one after the other

```
$ make DEBUG=1 TRAIT_A=1
mkdir -p obj/debug/TRAIT_A
g++ -c -o obj/debug/TRAIT_A/main.o -DTRAIT_A     -frecord-gcc-switches -O0 -g main.cpp
mkdir -p bin/debug/TRAIT_A
g++ -DTRAIT_A    -frecord-gcc-switches -O0 -g -o bin/debug/TRAIT_A/prog  obj/debug/TRAIT_A/main.o

$ make DEBUG=1 TRAIT_B=1
mkdir -p obj/debug/TRAIT_B
g++ -c -o obj/debug/TRAIT_B/main.o -DTRAIT_B     -frecord-gcc-switches -O0 -g main.cpp
mkdir -p bin/debug/TRAIT_B
g++ -DTRAIT_B    -frecord-gcc-switches -O0 -g -o bin/debug/TRAIT_B/prog  obj/debug/TRAIT_B/main.o

$ make RELEASE=1 TRAIT_A=1 TRAIT_B=1
mkdir -p obj/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B
g++ -c -o obj/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B/main.o -DNDEBUG -DTRAIT_A      -DTRAIT_B   -frecord-gcc-switches -O3 main.cpp
mkdir -p bin/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B
g++ -DNDEBUG -DTRAIT_A   -DTRAIT_B   -frecord-gcc-switches -O3 -o bin/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B/prog  obj/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B/main.o

$ make RELEASE=1
g++ -c -o obj/release/main.o -DNDEBUG -frecord-gcc-switches -O3 main.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -frecord-gcc-switches -O3 -o bin/release/prog  obj/release/main.o
```

That last one is the release variant with neither `TRAIT_A` nor `TRAIT_B`.

We've now built four versions of program `prog` in different `./bin[/...]` subdirectories
of the project, from different object files that are in different `./obj[/...]` subdirectories,
and those versions will all tell us how they were differently built. Running in the order
we built them:-

```
$ bin/debug/TRAIT_A/prog

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
  [    1d]  -D_GNU_SOURCE
  [    2b]  -D TRAIT_A
  [    36]  main.cpp
  [    3f]  -mtune=generic
  [    4e]  -march=x86-64
  [    5c]  -auxbase-strip obj/debug/TRAIT_A/main.o
  [    84]  -g
  [    87]  -O0
  [    8b]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    a1]  -fstack-protector-strong
  [    ba]  -Wformat
  [    c3]  -Wformat-security

$ bin/debug/TRAIT_B/prog

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
  [    1d]  -D_GNU_SOURCE
  [    2b]  -D TRAIT_B
  [    36]  main.cpp
  [    3f]  -mtune=generic
  [    4e]  -march=x86-64
  [    5c]  -auxbase-strip obj/debug/TRAIT_B/main.o
  [    84]  -g
  [    87]  -O0
  [    8b]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    a1]  -fstack-protector-strong
  [    ba]  -Wformat
  [    c3]  -Wformat-security

$ bin/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B/prog

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
  [    1d]  -D_GNU_SOURCE
  [    2b]  -D NDEBUG
  [    35]  -D TRAIT_A
  [    40]  -D TRAIT_B
  [    4b]  main.cpp
  [    54]  -mtune=generic
  [    63]  -march=x86-64
  [    71]  -auxbase-strip obj/release/TRAIT_A/TRAIT_B/main.o
  [    a3]  -O3
  [    a7]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    bd]  -fstack-protector-strong
  [    d6]  -Wformat
  [    df]  -Wformat-security

$ bin/release/prog

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  [     0]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu
  [    1d]  -D_GNU_SOURCE
  [    2b]  -D NDEBUG
  [    35]  main.cpp
  [    3e]  -mtune=generic
  [    4d]  -march=x86-64
  [    5b]  -auxbase-strip obj/release/main.o
  [    7d]  -O3
  [    81]  -frecord-gcc-switches
  [    97]  -fstack-protector-strong
  [    b0]  -Wformat
  [    b9]  -Wformat-security
```

We can clean the first one:

```
$ make DEBUG=1 TRAIT_A=1 clean
rm -f ./bin/debug/TRAIT_A/prog ./obj/debug/TRAIT_A/main.o
```

And the last one:

```
$ make RELEASE=1 clean
rm -f ./bin/release/prog ./obj/release/main.o
```

The second and third are still there and up to date:

```
$ make DEBUG=1 TRAIT_B=1
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

$ make RELEASE=1 TRAIT_A=1 TRAIT_B=1
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

For the exercise, you might consider refining the makefile to let you build, or clean,
all the variants at the same time. Or to default to `DEBUG` if `RELEASE` not is defined, or vice versa. Or to fail if no valid combination of traits is selected, for some definition of *valid*.

BTW, note that *preprocessor* options are conventionally assigned in the make variable
`CPPFLAGS`, for either C or C++ compilation; C *compiler* options are assigned
in `CFLAGS` and C++ *compiler* options in `CXXFLAGS`. GNU Make's built-in
rules *assume* that you follow these conventions.

Comment: This is a very precise answer and I really appreciate it. I will use this approach of creating directories that are relevant to my options and put both the object files and final executables there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is a good idea to just use the binary name to separate different build configurations. Won't a change in the compiler options still cause the object files to be stomped on since I presume they will be named the same as the source files, and it will still effectively be a full rebuild anyway?

This looks to me as a prime candidate for out-of-source builds. Configure your build scripts to create all intermediate and output files in a separate directory outside the source directory. Each different set of build options will use a different build directory, perhaps choosing a directory name dynamically based on the hash of the compiler flags as you suggested.

This will give you a clean source tree, and by changing the compiler options in the makefile/build scripts you will change to which directory the intermediate and output files will be placed.